# Visual Studio 2015 test not discovered for x86

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am using VS 2015 and I created a new “Unit Test App (Windows Universal)”.

- If the *Default Processor Architecture* is set to x64 (under “Test -> Test Settings -> Default Processor Architecture”), the build works fine and the test is also discovered successfully and displayed by the Test Explorer
- However, if I change the *Default Processor Architecture* to x86, the build still succeeds, but VS does not discover any tests.

Thoughts?

P.S. I have looked at some of the similar problems that have been asked here. If you think this is a duplicate, please confirm with me before flagging the question. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the larger audience: It seems like there was something that I was missing while installing Visual Studio that resulted in this issue. I reinstalled VS from scratch, and everything works as expected.

Answer (score -1):

I just hit this too.
For me the root cause was that the Build target must match the Test Settings Default Processor Architecture.

New Projects (even Universal Windows projects) always default to Any CPU.
If you are running on x64 machine then your Test Settings Default Processor Architecture has to be x64 too.

In my opinion Universal Windows projects should never have an "Any CPU" config.
Universal always has to build native now so stop the "Any CPU" option and make the user pick the target!